# Center a vector img in a responsive div box?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, center

I have a vector img that appears, with the correct dimensions, in a responsive div-box using this css:

```
.col1 > div {
  width:100%;
  height:25%;
  position: relative;
}
.thisIMGcontainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
}
.thisIMG {
  background-image: url('../img/thisIMG.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

For this HTML:

```
<div class="col1">
    <div class="box1">
      <div class="thisIMGcontainer"><div class="thisIMG"></div></div>
    </div><!--/box1-->
</div>
```

I have tried multiple combinations of CSS to get the img aligned in the center, but it either remains aligned to the left, or it randomly disappears!

> display: table-caption; or display: inline-block; and margin: 0 auto;

Comment: PNG is not a vector image, by the way.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin thanks for pointing this out.. what formats are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You image div has no width, so it takes all available width - 100%. If you want an image to be centered, you either have to use `<img>` tag instead of using a background image, or you have to set a width in `.thisIMG` class.

Comment: thanks for the tip.. even removing all the css, with <img> it's simply filling the div box, with only the top half of the image showing?

Comment: You do not need `.thisIMGcontainer` div at all.